# Postman websocket request using OWIN startup class

Tags: vb.net, websocket, postman, signalr, owin

I have a webapp project that is in VB.net. I am trying to create aPostman Websocket request to connect my SignalR hub but I am not able to and I am getting 400 (Unexpected server response).
Project is using .Net framework 4.8.
I am able to create console app which acts as a client and I can connect and even use a hub perfectly fine from that console app.
Issue comes when I try to create a websocket request in Postman.

I have created a sample webapp project in .Netcore and I can connect my Signal r hub using postman websocket request.So the issue comes with the .Net Framework.

This is the code I have added in OWIN startup class in Configuration Method

```
app.MapSignalR("/Signalr", New Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.HubConfiguration())
```

Any help will be appreciated.SIgnalr version is 2.4.3